# Using Google Fit API to get steps with and without Fit App installed and possible working offline

Tags: android, api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to develop an application that can count steps. I am using Xamarin.Forms, so I will have to make the Android part and the iOS part.

In the Android, I want to use Google Fit API's. I already implemented History API, to get the last week buckets of steps, and it is working. But this only works if the Google Fit App is installed. But I want to have an application that is independent of Google Fit App. So, I think I need to use the Google Fit Record API or Google Fit Sensors API. I think the Record API is automatically saving the sensor data to the History API database. However, to do this I will need Network access, right? If yes, I would like to use it when a network is available (and GoogleFit app is not installed). But when it is not available maybe the Sensors API is the right answer. Using Sensors API, should I create a Background Service (working even if the app is closed) that receive sensor data and periodically save data to a SQLite database (I already have this DB implemented)?

Am I dificulting this a lot and I just need to use one API for everything? I want Google Fit API because I would like to append wearables to the account when possible.

I really need help to understand what it is possible or not, please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With Android 4.4 also comes support for two new composite sensors: Step Detector and Step Counter http://blog.bawa.com/2013/11/create-your-own-simple-pedometer.html
 or it can also help you code this repo https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer

Comment: I think Pedometer is only compatible with Android 4.4 and Nexus 5, just like your first link cites...